# Data Extract and Fie Transfer Activity failing sometimes in Automation Studio due to an hour change

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, automationstudio, data-extract

We are running two automations each automation is with 2 Data Extract activities followed by a File Transfer activity in Marketing Cloud Automation Studio.

These two automations are running continuously triggering each other using SSJS activity at the end of each automation.

And in data extract and file transfer activities we are using filename pattern user_YYYY_MM_DD-HH
as we need new file name every time to transfer to external SFTP , we can not use same name for different file we are dropping to external SFTP.

**Challenge**

Sine these 2 automations are running continuously there are some instances where 2nd Data Extract activity and file transfer activity is failing due to the the change in hour - for example Data Extract ran at 12.59PM and File Transfer Started and finished at 1.01 PM as there is a change in Hour in file name File Transfer will encounter an error as there is no file matched with that time stamp causing Automation to stop.

Do we have any solution for this issue ? We were thinking to use SafeHouse File Delete Option (Available in Data extract activity) to delete file from safe house once tranfer done but that will also wont work as there are similar chances hour change will happen between File Transfer and File Delete activity which wont delete file from safehouse .

Please let me know if we have any solution for this issue ?

Comment: Do you need to have all the different files on SFTP? If you would simply have the "user_YYYY_MM_DD" format, the files would be overwritten every time, yet consistently working.